# NumPy: get higher value between two columns

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Having this:

```
g2 = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],[1,2,1,3,4,5,6,7,9,2],[2,3,4,1,3,6,1,1,2,9]])
print g2.T
[[ 1  1  2]
 [ 2  2  3]
 [ 3  1  4]
 [ 4  3  1]
 [ 5  4  3]
 [ 6  5  6]
 [ 7  6  1]
 [ 8  7  1]
 [ 9  9  2]
 [10  2  9]]
```

How can I print in a nice way? For each row, the number of the column of the higher value between the last two columns.

I would like something like this:

```
 [[ 1 column 3 ]
 [ 2  column 3]
 [ 3  column 3]
 [ 4  column 3]
 [ 5  column 2]
 [ 6  column 2]
 [ 7  column 3]
 [ 8  column 2]
 [ 9  column 3]
 [10  column 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `argmax` to find the index of the maximum values. First select the last two columns using `g2.T[:, 1:]` and then compute `argmax` across axis 1.

Since you've stated that you're labeling the columns as 1, 2 and 3, you'll need to add `2` to what `argmax` returns:

```
>>> np.argmax(g2.T[:, 1:], axis=1) + 2
array([3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3], dtype=int64)
```

If you want to stack this array with the first column of your array `g2.T`, you can use `column_stack`. The whole thing looks like this:

```
>>> np.column_stack((g2.T[:, 0], np.argmax(g2.T[:, 1:], axis=1) + 2))
array([[ 1,  3],
       [ 2,  3],
       [ 3,  3],
       [ 4,  2],
       [ 5,  2],
       [ 6,  3],
       [ 7,  2],
       [ 8,  2],
       [ 9,  2],
       [10,  3]], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: @aspire57: does this answer address your question? Let me know if anything isn't clear.